# Sectioned RecyclerView with different layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I had a scenario where I need to create a RecyclerView with 3 sections 
The first section named as "First" should display 3 rows with each row containing TextView and EditText  
Second section named as "Second" should contain  2 rows with each row displaying a single TextView

Third section named as "Third" should contain  4 rows with each row displaying a TextView with image 
. Is there a way in which can I achieve this using RecyclerView ? 
 Can any one share me links or sample code fragments to achieve this functionality

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) to group your data into sections.

First create a Section class:

```
class MyFirstSection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MyFirstSection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data for each year
MyFirstSection section1 = new MyFirstSection("First", firstDataList);
MySecondSection section2 = new MySecondSection("Second", secondDataList);
MyThirdSection section3 = new MyThirdSection("Third", thirdDataList);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(section1);
sectionAdapter.addSection(section2);
sectionAdapter.addSection(section3);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Comment: will check the library

Comment: this library is good and easy to use though i am facing problem in working with horizontal scroll recyclerview and also item gets duplicate on every refresh please help me with this problem.